# delete cell when other cell is blank VBA excell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm going to start by saying I'm not very good with coding.

The issue I'm having is when I delete my text in cell "L" the date stays in cell "J". How do I make it automatically delete itself if "L" is blank? Basically if a cell in "L" is blank I want the corresponding cell in "J" to be blank.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim L As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set L = Range("L:L")
    Set Inte = Intersect(L, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            ActiveSheet.Range("J" & r.Row).Value = Date
            Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work this in to the code:

```
Range("L1:L10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(0, -2).ClearContents
```

Just adjust the range as necessary.

Comment: (@Jeremie - Hurray! If that solved it for you, mind flagging as The Answer? You can do so by clicking the check mark left of the post, below the up/down arrows)